# how to make two docker containers share sqllite db on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to build an application which in essence consists of two parts.

1. Django based api
2. SQLite database.

Api interacts with the SQLite database, but has only read only access. However, the SQLite database needs to be updated every N minutes. So my plan was to make two docker container. First one, for the api. The second one, for the script which is executed every N minutes using CRON (Ubuntu) to update the database.

I am using Kubernetes to serve my applications. So I was wondering if there is a way to achieve what I want here?

I've researched about Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes, but still do not see how I can make it work.

EDIT:

So I have figured that I can use one pod two share two containers on Kubernetes and this way make use of the emptyDir. My question is then, how do I define the path to this directory in my python files?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: the db ideally needs to go in its own container; can you switch db or use another tool to access sqllite over the network?

Comment: Accessing the db should not be a problem as long as I have the url and right credentials, right? I was researching and I think that the emptydir on Kubernetes could be an answer here?

Comment: I don't think sqlite has any network access by default?

Comment: I think there are some solutions, for instance Sqlite Network, but I'd rather stay away from those. Ideally, I would like to create a sqlite database in emptydir of a pod where two containers are running. Then give access to it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that `emptyDir` is erased every time the pod is stopped/killed (you do a deployment, a node crash, etc.). See the doc for more details: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir

Taking that into account, if that solves your problem, then you just need to put the `mountPath` to the directory you want, as in the link above shows the example.

Take into account that the whole directory will be empty, so if you have other things there they won't be visible if you set up and `emptyDir` (just typical unix mount semantics, nothing k8s specific here)